# Next-Auth + Prism error - "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I've set up next-auth to use EmailProvider and a prisma adapter as described in the documentation

authOptions

```
const prisma = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient();
globalThis.prisma = prisma;

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
        server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
        from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
    })
}
```

.env

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://dbname:password@localhost:5432/dbname?schema=public
EMAIL_SERVER=smtp://admin@myemail.ca:password@mail.privateemail.com:465
EMAIL_FROM=from@email.com
```

I haven't changed anything in the config and have tried a clean install. The prisma is connecting to my DB with no issues.

The stack trace below makes reference to getAdapterUserFromEmail, which is calling getUserByEmail. In getUserByEmail, the prisma client is suddenly undefined. I can see the client is getting created when the PrismaAdapter methods are defined, but it's undefined by the time the method is called.

next-auth/core/lib/email/getUserFromEmail

```
async function getAdapterUserFromEmail({
  email,
  adapter
}) {
  const {
    getUserByEmail
  } = adapter;
  const adapterUser = email ? await getUserByEmail(email) : null; //CALLS getUserByEmail HERE. Email is a string because I just signed in
  if (adapterUser) return adapterUser;
  return {
    id: email,
    email,
    emailVerified: null
  };
}
```

@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:

```
function PrismaAdapter(p) {
    return {
        createUser: (data) => p.user.create({ data }),
        getUser: (id) => p.user.findUnique({ where: { id } }),
        getUserByEmail: (email) => getUserByEmail: (email) => {
            p.user.findUnique({ where: { email } }) //Why is p undefined?? :( 

        },
}
}
```

Stack trace:

```
error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user')
    at getUserByEmail (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:8:38)
    at _callee2$ (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next-auth/core/errors.js:365:29)
    at tryCatch (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:44:17)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:125:22)
    at Generator.next (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:69:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _next (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:22:9)
    at /Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:27:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:19:12
    at getAdapterUserFromEmail (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next-auth/core/lib/email/getUserFromEmail.js:15:37)
    at Object.signin (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/signin.js:77:54)
    at AuthHandler (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:253:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async NextAuthHandler (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:23:19)
    at async /Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:59:32
    at async Object.apiResolver (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:363:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:487:9)
    at async Object.fn (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:749:37)
    at async Router.execute (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:253:36)
    at async DevServer.run (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:384:29)
    at async DevServer.run (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:741:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (/Users/ryan/Documents/Projects/animated_section_builder/app-platform/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:322:20) {
  name: 'GetUserByEmailError',
  code: undefined,
  page: '/api/auth/[
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have it figured out by now, but I just had the same problem.
In my case, it seems the problem was with PrismaClient import in the lib folder where I had the prisma instance.
The error I was getting was this:

```
Module '"@prisma/client"' has no exported member 'PrismaClient'.ts
```

I deleted node_modules and reinstalled prisma and everything again and that solved the issue. Not sure what caused it in the first place. Prisma was working fine before I installed next-auth.